# Lazy generic type pass in java

Tags: java, generics

Let's say i have simple interface `Status`

```
interface Status {
    Integer getNumber();
}
```

and have simple interface to retrieve it:

```
interface A<T extends Status> {
    T getStatus();
}
```

What i am interested in can i make simplified version of:

```
interface DateStatus extends Status {
    Date getDate();
}

interface B<T extends DateStatus> extends A<T> {

}
```

For interface `B` method extended from `A`, `getStatus()` returns an instance of `DateStatus`?

simple example:

```
A.getStatus() -> Status

B.getStatus() -> Status

B<DateStatus>.getStatus() -> DateStatus
```

how can i achieve `B.getStatus()` -> `DateStatus` without adding wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is in the definition of B override the *getStatus*:

```
public interface B<T extends DateStatus> extends A<T> {
    @Override
    T getStatus();
}
```

Comment: I thought about this method but it have 1 problem i don't like in particular,
Outsider who looks at B interface will see 2 methods:

        `Status getStatus()`

        `DateStatus getStatus()`

inside interface B

Comment: Well without it (due to Java's type erasure) there is a Catch-22 there.